# Differentiate between Shell Variables and Cloudformation template parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have come across a usecase where i am seeing conflict between `Shell Variables` and `Cloudformation Parameters`.

Example:

I am writing `AWS::ImageBuilder::Component`

```
Parameters:
  cloudVersion:
    Type: String
    Default: "1.10.11"
    Description: Cloud Version to release
Resources:
  CloudInstallComponent:
    Type: AWS::ImageBuilder::Component
    Properties:
      Name: CloudAMI
      Version: !Ref cloudVersion
      Description: Install the latest cloud.
      ChangeDescription: Cloud First version
      Platform: Linux
      Data: !Sub |
        name: DeployCloudComponents
        description: This is to deploy cloud components.
        schemaVersion: 1.0
        phases:
          - name: build
            steps:
              - name: CreateUser
                action: ExecuteBash
                inputs:
                  commands:
                    - "Creating New User cloud"
                    - export GroupID=7560
                    - export UserID=7560
                    - export USER=cloud
                    - sudo groupadd --gid ${GroupID} ${USER}
                    - sudo useradd --uid ${UserID} --gid ${GroupID} --create-home --shell /bin/bash ${USER}
                    - sudo usermod -G wheel ${USER}
                    - |-
                        echo "${USER}    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
                    - sudo wget -O a.tgz 'abc.net/mg/api/v1/help/${cloudVersion}/on/download/a.tgz'
```

Now in above code snippet `GroupID`, `UserID` and `USER` are shell variables while `cloudVersion` is cloudformation parameter.

Question is how to differentiate between them ?

I am seeing errors in cfn-linter like below

```
Error   Cfn-Lint    Parameter GroupID for Fn::Sub not found at Resources/CloudInstallComponent/Properties/Data/Fn::Sub  160:7
Error   Cfn-Lint    Parameter USER for Fn::Sub not found at Resources/K2CloudInstallComponent/Properties/Data/Fn::Sub   160:7
Error   Cfn-Lint    Parameter UserID for Fn::Sub not found at Resources/K2CloudInstallComponent/Properties/Data/Fn::Sub 160:7
```

I can solve the ambiguity by taking three shell variables as cloudformation parameters.

But if anyone can suggest an existing way to differentiate between both kind of variables would be good.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you attempt to actually deploy it? sometimes cfn-linter is incorrect.

Comment: Yes when i run the template it gives me the error `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [USER, UserId, GroupId] in the Resources block of the template`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to [escape](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-sub.html) your variables using `${!}` notation:

```
Parameters:
  cloudVersion:
    Type: String
    Default: "1.10.11"
    Description: Cloud Version to release
Resources:
  CloudInstallComponent:
    Type: AWS::ImageBuilder::Component
    Properties:
      Name: CloudAMI
      Version: !Ref cloudVersion
      Description: Install the latest cloud.
      ChangeDescription: Cloud First version
      Platform: Linux
      Data: !Sub |
        name: DeployCloudComponents
        description: This is to deploy cloud components.
        schemaVersion: 1.0
        phases:
          - name: build
            steps:
              - name: CreateUser
                action: ExecuteBash
                inputs:
                  commands:
                    - "Creating New User cloud"
                    - export GroupID=7560
                    - export UserID=7560
                    - export USER=cloud
                    - sudo groupadd --gid ${!GroupID} ${!USER}
                    - sudo useradd --uid ${!UserID} --gid ${!GroupID} --create-home --shell /bin/bash ${!USER}
                    - sudo usermod -G wheel ${!USER}
                    - |-
                        echo "${!USER}    ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
                    - sudo wget -O a.tgz 'abc.net/mg/api/v1/help/${cloudVersion}/on/download/a.tgz'
```